# split char array as first name, middle name and last name, skip middle name if its empty in C language

Tags: c

```
token1 = strtok(udtAddressVar.strName, " ");
strcpy(udtAddressVar.strFirstName, token1);
token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(udtAddressVar.strMiddleName, token1);
token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(udtAddressVar.strLastName, token1);
```

using this code but it fails when there is no middle name. For example works fine for 'John Henry Blue' and not for 'Brad Henry'

Comment: Have you tried to set a default value for each variable? I mean, strFirstName, strMiddleName and strLastName in the beggining has NULL values, try to initialize all of them to a blank string such as "", because I think you are getting an error because of put a null in the parameter.

Comment: They are all initialized as empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most things, it's always a good idea to test the results of a function to make sure it's done what you think it has. And by doing so, you can solve your problem as well.

```
token1 = strtok(udtAddressVar.strName, " ");
if(token1)
  {
  strcpy(udtAddressVar.strFirstName, token1);
  token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if(token1)
    { 
    strcpy(udtAddressVar.strMiddleName, token1);
    token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(token1)
      {
      strcpy(udtAddressVar.strLastName, token1);
      }
    else
      {
      strcpy(udtAddressVar.strLastName, udtAddressVar.strMiddleName);
      *udtAddressVar.strMiddleName='\0';
      }
    }
  }
```

You could also expand this yet further to deal with the case where you have 2 or more middle names too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `token1` is null before trying to read the surname:

```
// get the first token
token1 = strtok(udtAddressVar.strName, " ");
strcpy(udtAddressVar.strFirstName, token1);

// middle name
token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(udtAddressVar.strMiddleName, token1);

// Check if the last name exists
if (token1 == NULL) {
    udtAddressVar.strLastName = udtAddressVar.strMiddleName;
    udtAddressVar.strMiddleName = "";
}
// get the last name 
else {
    token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    strcpy(udtAddressVar.strLastName, token1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
token1 = strtok(udtAddressVar.strName, " ");
strcpy(udtAddressVar.strFirstName, token1);
token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
token3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
if (token3) {
  strcpy(udtAddressVar.strMiddleName, token2);
  strcpy(udtAddressVar.strLastName, token3);
} else {
  udtAddressVar.strMiddleName[0] = '\0';
  strcpy(udtAddressVar.strLastName, token2);
}
```